# How to show a message after Redux dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux

When a button is clicked I call the following:

```
this.props.dispatch(addNote(this.state.noteContent))
```

This in turn calls the following action:

```
export default function addNote(note){
  return dispatch => {
    axios.post('http://localhost:2403/notes', {
        Body: note
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        dispatch({
            type: ADD_NOTE,
            payload: response.data
        })
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    })
  }
}
```

My reducer then updates the state and a new note is added to the list, so it's all working correctly.

However I now want to show a message in the UI which says "Note has been added successfully". Ideally, this would be a part of a wider notifications system, but for now, I just need to figure out how to report success (or failure) on this one action.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a promise from your dispatch using [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk), why not use that?  Try this code in your thunk:

```
export default function addNote(note){
    return dispatch => {
        return axios.post('http://localhost:2403/notes', {
            Body: note
        })
        ... //function continues
```

Then you can do:

```
this.props.dispatch(addNote(this.state.noteContent)).then(successFunc, failureFunc);

successFunc = function() {
    //Show message on UI
}
```

Comment: I have tried this several times already but get the following error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Comment: @MattSaunders I've edited this to show how to return a promise, as your code is currently not doing so.  You need to return the result of the `axios.post`

Comment: Ah yes, it took a moment for me to see the return statement which was missing. Thanks!

Comment: `.then(successFunc, failureFunc)` is this correct ???? ..... should n't be a catch block instead. please clarify ..  do we need to call or pass `successFunc` `failureFunc` while returning from action @ScoobyDrew18

Comment: Another question ... i just removed  `return dispatch => {` block from above mentioned code snippet .. now it's working .... without   `return dispatch => {` and using `.then((data)=>{.....}).catch((err)=>{.....})` ... is this the correct way ?????... please clarify .... it's working for me this way.... thanks in advance for your time. @ScoobyDrew18

Comment: @kumarkundan If it's working for you then I suppose it's not incorrect, but if you're removing all that code then you aren't leveraging the promise which was the point of my answer.

Comment: i am leveraging the promise ... i am returning `promise` from respective `action` and catching it using `.then() ` ... my question is what is the purpose of `return dispatch => {` @ScoobyDrew18

Answer (score 1):

You can use a toast component (like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify) that sits on top of your routes in your app that renders every time an action in redux is called.

In each of your action functions, you can have a call to a message reducer that updates the state inside message reducer.  Each time the state in that reducer is changed, the toast component will re-render and last for a certain amount of time or until a user manually closes the toast component.

Comment: I appreciate this but really, I want a bare bones solution which I can build upon. There must be a relatively simple way to achieve this natively with Redux?